# Get original and current prices with a subquery in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, sql-order-by, ionos

I have a table of **ads** and another of **prices**, relative to these ads. When the user modifies a price in the application, a new row is added to the prices table, which includes the price and the date the price was modified.

I need to **get** a list with all the ads and, for each ad, **the first price** that was registered, **and also the last**. I have used a double subquery on the same price table.

### Tables

#### `ads`

| id `int` | ad_title `varchar` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Potatoes |
| 2 | Tomatoes |

#### `prices`

| id `int` | price `decimal` | price_timestamp `timestamp` | ads_id `int` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2021-02-16 21:12:36 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2021-02-17 21:12:48 | 1 |
| 3 | 1000 | 2021-02-17 21:20:40 | 2 |
| 4 | 900 | 2021-02-18 13:20:49 | 2 |
| 5 | 700 | 2021-02-18 13:20:49 | 2 |

### Query

```sql
    SELECT ads.ad_title, prices_firsts.price AS price_first, prices_currents.price AS price_current
    FROM ads
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM prices
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY price_timestamp ASC
    ) prices_firsts ON prices_firsts.ads_id = ads.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM prices
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY price_timestamp DESC
    ) prices_currents ON prices_currents.ads_id = ads.id
    GROUP BY ads.id
```

Esta consulta devuelve lo siguiente en mi **servidor local** (XAMPP):

| ad_title | price_first | price_current |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Potatoes | 50 | 5 |
| Tomatoes | 1000 | 700 |

As you can see **the result of the query is correct** **BUT** when it is executed on a server from an external provider (I have tested it in 1&1 IONOS and in Arsys Spain) the results vary practically with each execution. There are times when prices appear in reverse order, sometimes the same price appears in both columns...

## What I need?

I need to understand if the problem is in the servers configuration of these providers or if the query is wrong.

I am also open to ideas that you can contribute to get the prices (first and current) in another way, even if it is with another structure in the database.

Comment: Great news: in the absence of any aggregating functions a GROUP BY clause is NEVER appropriate

Comment: If the result of this query is ever 'correct', that is a consequence of luck, rather than design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try using a subquery for min and max date

```
    select ads.id, p1.price min_price, p2.price max_price,
from ads 
inner join (

    select  ads_id, min(price_timestamp ) min_date, max(price_timestamp )  max_date 
    from prices 
    group by ads_id

 ) t on t.ads_id = ads.id 
 INNER JOIN prices p1 on p1.ads_id = ads.id and p1.price_timestamp = t.min_date
 INNER JOIN prices p2 on p2.ads_id = ads.id and p2.price_timestamp = t.mmaxn_date
```

Comment: Wow! thanks to your explanation I have been able to understand how it works. Thanks ;)